Azure databricks job run Customized value at runtime
How can I modify the Staus and Error code values from notebook.
At present it is showing Status Succeeded but when will go inside notebook.

There is no data in source so notebook exited. What I need Status should come Succeeded but ErrorCode value should come as No data in source.

Is there any way to customized the value during jobrun.

Execpted output - if no data then some how if we are able to fail the pipline but in error code value should come as No data found, instead of RunExecutionError.


What you are thinking is not the correct way.
dbutils.notebook.exit return the value to source from where it is called and not to the workflow environment.
When the status is succeeded, of course the error code will be empty unless the notebook fails.
Error code is intended to show only the error message when the notebook execution fails.
So, what you want to handle is either you print your custom message or set it as task values so other task can access the message.
Here, is the sample code.
try:
    
    if df.count() == 0:
        # If no data is found, raise a custom exception
        raise ValueError("No data in source")
    
    # Process your data
    # ...

    # If everything is successful, you can log a success message
    print("Status: Succeeded")
    print("ErrorCode: None")

except Exception as e:

    if str(e) == "No data in source":
        print("Status: Succeeded")
        print("ErrorCode: No data in source")
    else:
        print("Status: Failed")
        print(f"ErrorCode: {e}")



Hello I have tried your approach and updated my question. Still that is on the Notebook level, how can I pass those values to job run error code value should come (No data found.)

I think you haven't read my solution clearly. please read the solution properly what i have mentioned.

I have read your answer, but my question is different I need to set the Status and error code values from notebook in JOB run PAGE. I got to know these values are static from databricks we can'nt change it.

No you can not the set them manually. They are thrown based based on your notebook succeeded or not.

And why are you expecting to set the error message while your notebook status is succeeded.

Reason for setting those paramter value as no data found, we have UI also on top of that will check the status value so if it is succeeded then business user  will think data is processed but ideally there is no data itself to process.
